# Get key value from QString which contains JSON

Tags: json, qstring

I have a text box, where a JSON string is put.
I want to send key-value pairs to a web service. For this I need to parse QString to smth, iterate in this smth, putting key-value to QUrlQuery.

```
QByteArray qba01 = QByteArray();
qba01.append(ui->inputPTE->toPlainText());
QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData(qba01);
QJsonObject jsonObject = d.object();

// set request's parameters
QUrlQuery query;
foreach(QString keyValue, jsonObject.keys()) {
    query.addQueryItem(keyValue, jsonObject.value(keyValue).toString());
}
serviceUrl.setQuery(query.query());
```

My string is

> { "param1" : "2011-11-11 11:41:11", "param2" : "value2" }

I don't get key-value pairs. Can anyone please point me out where is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(ui->inputPTE->toPlainText().toUtf8());
```